# Creating AWS RDS Postgres with CDK and defining Security Groups

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-context

I'm using python CDK to create a Postgres DB and all is fine.

I'm using

```
newdatabase = rds.DatabaseCluster(

)
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to attach an existing security group to this cluster. Anyone know how I could do it with Python?

Answer (score 0):

You set it using [DatabaseClusterAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_rds/DatabaseClusterAttributes.html). Specifically using:

> security_groups - The security groups of the database cluster. Default: - no security groups

Comment: I actually tried this, but got some odd errors where it said my security group needed to be an Array, but the docs say Isecuritygroup   go figure...

Comment: @JimmyChen You would have to show actual code that you used.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling the existing security group as shown below and then using the variable in the array. It worked for me.

```
security_group = _ec2.SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id(self, "imported-sg",security_group_id="sg-xxxxxxxx")
```

```
mydb= _rds.DatabaseInstance(self,
                              "mysql-rds",
                              security_groups=[security_group]
                            )
```